# Unbind/bind new Bluetooth Device Driver - Ubuntu 14.04 Trust Tahr

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, bluetooth, usb-device

### Preface

II swallowed the first 3-chapters of the [Linux Device Drivers, Edition 3 - PDF](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/), so I know a bit more about it than I did at the start of the week, but still not so much.

### System

- Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, Trusty Tahr
- Kernel: 4.4.0-47-Generic

### Problem

I am trying to replace the kernel `btusb` driver with the Bluetopia USB BT driver `SS1BTUSB` (Driver source and build files from [CodeAurora](https://www.codeaurora.org/projects/all-active-projects/bluetopia-drivers)), because I am trying to learn more about the Bluetopia Bluetooth stack implementation, and this is the first step to being able to do that.

I can successfully build the `SS1BTUSB` Kernel module and install it.

```
$ sudo insmod SS1BTUSBM.ko

$ lsmod | grep SS1BTUSB
SS1BTUSBM              32768  0
```

And, following the instructions from the [lwn.net article](https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/), I can unbind the devices attached to the `btusb` driver.

```
$ ls /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb
1-1.5:1.0  1-1.5:1.1  bind  module  new_id  remove_id  uevent  unbind
$ sudo -i
# echo "1-1.5:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/unbind
# echo "1-1.5:1.1" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/unbind
-bash: echo: write error: No such device
# ls /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb
bind  module  new_id  remove_id  uevent  unbind
```

I am not sure why unbinding the second device causes the error but the result is the devices are unbound from the `btusb` driver.

However, when I try and bind these devices to the `SS1BTUSB1` driver, I get the same error.

```
# echo "1-1.5:1.1" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/SS1BTUSB/bind
-bash: echo: write error: No such device
# echo "1-1.5:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/SS1BTUSB/bind
-bash: echo: write error: No such device
```

It seems that the 'No such device' error is fairly generic and could mean any number of things, suggestions on how to debug/diagnose this issue would be greatly appreciated.

### Random Notes

(May or may not help diagnose the problem).

The `btusb` driver is used by other drivers - could be related.

```
$ lsmod | grep btusb
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             516096  25 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
```

USB info on the Bluetooth USB dongle...

```
$ lsusb
.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a12:1243 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd
.
```

It's actually a CSR8675 Headset Development Board configured as a BT dongle (this bit I know about), so it's details look a bit screwy...

```
$ usb-devices
.
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=04 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0a12 ProdID=1243 Rev=20.32
S:  Product=CSR8675 USB Headset
S:  SerialNumber=ABCDEF0123456789
C:  #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=fe(app. ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
.
```

But it is a functional Bluetooth HCI device.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out that the Bluetopia device driver `SS1BTUSB` is very specific about the Bluetooth devices it supports. A lot more specific than the kernel `btusb` driver.

From the SS1BTUSB.c `BluetoothDeviceIDTable[]`...

```
   /* CSR Module.                                             */
   { USB_DEVICE(0x0A12, 0x0001) },
   { USB_DEVICE(0x0A12, 0x0043) },
   { USB_DEVICE(0x0A12, 0x1000) },
```

I checked my Developer board... and its idProduct (USB Product ID code) is 0x1234.

```
$ lsusb -d 0a12:
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0a12:1234 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd
```

0x1234 is not in the table, or a even listed for any 'Cambridge Silicon Radio' devices at [www.linux-usb.org](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids).

Fortunately, changing the the DevBoards USB Product ID, I can do, so I changed it to 0x0001 - for 'HCI device'.

The result, the device is recognised as a Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)

```
$ lsusb -d 0a12:
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
```

And I can now  bind/unbind the devices "1-1.5:1-0" and "1-1.5:1-1" to the `SS1BTUSB` driver without error.

### Lessons Learned

1. The default kernel `btusb` driver is a lot more permissive about the USB Bluetooth devices it recognises, perhaps it just *knows* that all CSR devices are Bluetooth dongles.
2. Device driver error messages are quite obtuse. Even enabling the SS1BTUSB device driver DEBUG `printk` output didn't help.
3. As always, the only real documentation is the source code.